# wxPython movable object on resizable page

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I am trying to write a simple application that will allow buttons to be moved, I used an example I found here on Stack overflow - sorry I can't find the original link :(

The buttons move as expected, but as soon as the frame is resized the button positions get reset back to there original position and I don't understand as I am setting the position and not sure what is resetting them and why.

The code:

```
import wx

app = wx.App(False)
d = {}

def MouseDown(e):
    print('mouse down')
    o           = e.GetEventObject()
    sx,sy       = panel.ScreenToClient(o.GetPositionTuple())
    dx,dy       = panel.ScreenToClient(wx.GetMousePosition())
    o._x,o._y   = (sx-dx, sy-dy)
    d['d'] = o
    print(o)

def MouseMove(e):
    try:
        if 'd' in d:
            print("mouse move has been triggered")

            o = d['d']
            x, y = wx.GetMousePosition()
            o.SetPosition(wx.Point(x+o._x,y+o._y))
    except:
        print('fail')
        pass

def MouseUp(e):
    try:
        if 'd' in d: del d['d']
    except: pass

frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'simple.py')
panel = wx.Panel(frame)
box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
button1 = wx.Button(panel, -1, "foo")
box.Add(button1, 0, wx.ALL, 10)
button2 = wx.Button(panel, -1, "bar")
box.Add(button2, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

button1.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, MouseDown)
button2.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, MouseDown)

button1.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, MouseMove)
button2.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, MouseMove)

button1.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, MouseUp)
button2.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, MouseUp)

panel.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, MouseMove)
panel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, MouseUp)

panel.SetSizer(box)
panel.Layout()
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Sizer` is relocating the buttons when you ReSize the frame.
i.e. Doing its job

The sizer is responsible for laying out its contents.
You are manually moving items but once the frame is resized, the sizer/s are actuated and force sanity back onto the layout. Inadvertently, for you, undoing what you wished to happen.
If you want this functionality, which in a real application would be to invite chaos (no pun intended), use manual positioning and eschew sizers.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  Can you have manual positioning within an element of a sizer?

Comment: @LittleMissChaos In short, No. Not as you propose above in your code. With some hairy coding, you could change the relative positions, especially with a `GridBagSizer` but in essence, the position will be decided by sizer, dependent on how you populated the sizer. If you think of it as a team with designated player positions, they can't endlessly swap during the game. In effect, the sizer is the referee imposing the rules. You can of course choose to play in a free-for-all without a referee (`sizer`).